# Pointer Problems : Assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'int

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I've been reading the book "Jumping into C++", and am currently reading up on pointers. This is an exercise from the book:

"What are the final values in **`x`**, **`p_int`**, and **`p_p_int`** in the following code:

```
int x = 0;
int *p_int = & x;
int **p_p_int = & p_int;
*p_int = 12;
**p_p_int = 25;
p_int = 12;
*p_p_int = 3;
p_p_int = 27;
```

And I get the error:

> "Assigning to `int *` from incompatible type `int`"

On the last three lines.

I don't know why this is happening, and would appreciate any insight.

Furthermore, assuming that this code somehow works, I would think that since all pointers are just pointing towards a single memory (**`**p_p_int -> *p_int -> x`**), the last value assignment would dictate the final value of the memory location. However in the book, the answer is:

> **`x = 25, p_p_int = 27, p_int = 3`**

Is this correct? If so, could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Since this code is not, and never was, valid C++, it is meaningless to discuss what the output is.  Perhaps you should try [a different book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282).

Comment: If the other examples in the book are similar to this one, I would pick a different book.  There's a curated list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That book is old (2013) and says in the introduction that it does not include anything from the C++11 standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly assign an int to an int pointer like this: int *p = 6;?](/q/44966943/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see `p_int` has as static type `int *`, and on the last three line you are doing something like

```
p_int = 12;
```

where `12` is an int, and so can't be assigned to a pointer (same thing to the other 2 lines)

However, `x` `p_int` `p_p_int` have different values because `x` contains the integer value, `p_int` the address of `x` and `p_p_int` the address of `p_int`.

Also keep in mind that this is a """"compilable"""" C code, not C++, but you will get 3 warnings also on C compiler telling you that you are assigning to a pointer an incompatible type

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd just like a bit extra clarification. I understand what you say about them all having different values, but by dereferencing the pointers appropriately, they would all lead to the same value held in the memory, am I right?
So for example, **p_p_int, *p_int, and x would yield the same value?

Comment: yes exactly, but they are themself a "variable" with a value inside, that change between each one

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
p_int = 12;
*p_p_int = 3;
p_p_int = 27;
```

There is no way this compiles with any confirming C++ compiler. It is just ill-formed. Even if you used casts to make it work, you'd cause undefined behavior. [Try a different book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/10147399).

Comment: No, you're wrong. There is no undefined behavior. ["A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Explanation) There would be undefined behavior if the resulting pointer was de-referenced, but that does not occur here.

Comment: @JaMiT what you're saying is a major misconception. You *can* convert any integral type to a pointer, but then evaluating that pointer (`p_int = (int*)12;` evaluates `p_int`) causes undefined behavior if that pointer doesn't have a valid value categorized in [basic.compound](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3). Even if you don't dereference it. Hence `p_int = (int*)12` causes undefined behavior unless `12` happens to fit in one of the aforementioned categories, which is unlikely.

Comment: Since you like quoting the standard, could you quote the part that says assigning an invalid pointer is undefined? Your current explanation is lacking. (For example, when `p_int` is evaluated as part of `p_int = (int*)12`, there is a valid pointer in `p_int`. It's not until after the assignment that it gets an invalid value.)

Comment: @JaMiT C17: §6.3.2.3/5 *"An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a **trap representation**.68)"*

Comment: @JaMiT Also C17 §6.2.6.1/5 *"Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation is called a trap representation."*

Comment: @JaMiT  *"t's not until after the assignment that it gets an invalid value"* - The result of `p_int = (int*)12` as a whole expression is `p_int` after it's been assigned the invalid value. Meaning it is evaluated with the invalid value.

Comment: _§6.3.2.3/5:_ Specifies defined behavior. _§6.2.6.1/5_ Describes a trap representation, but that need not be relevant (at best you've shown that a trap representation **might** come into play). _Evaluation:_ The result of `p_int = (int*)12` as a whole expression is an lvalue referring to `p_int` [[expr.ass](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1)]. The evaluation of this lvalue expression determines the identity of an object [[basic.lval](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1)]. The potential for UB comes after conversion to a prvalue (the *value* of that object), which does not occur here.

Comment: @JaMiT it is very relevant. It says forming bit patterns that are not valid is UB. And any value that does not fit to [1. Null Pointer Value, 2. Pointer to an object, 3. Pointer to 1 passed an object, 4. Pointer to an object that is now out of scope (invalid)] is not valid. A pointer formally cannot hold any other value. Pointers are abstractions, mind you. They are not mere ints.

Comment: @JaMiT I asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60147025/10147399).

Comment: No, it discusses bit patterns that are not **values of the object type**; there is no mention of "valid". Take another look at the lead-in to the list in [basic.compound]: "Every **value of pointer type** is one of the following:" (emphasis added). Being in the list, an invalid pointer value is a value of pointer type. Also, the name tells you it is a value of pointer type (invalid *pointer value*). To get a trap representation, you need something outside the list, something that is neither a valid nor an invalid pointer value because it is not a pointer value at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207568/discussion-between-jamit-and-ayxan).

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p_int = & x;
int **p_p_int = & p_int;
```

These lines all point to the same memory in location (variable x).

Comment: Not really. `p_p_int` points to a variable that points to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three variables in your code snippet. Here is a table showing the value each variable would have after the execution of each of the lines (if the code were to actually compile).

```
                         |  x | p_int | p_p_int |
-------------------------+----+-------+---------|
int x = 0;               |  0 | undef |  undef  |
int *p_int = & x;        |  0 |   &x  |  undef  |
int **p_p_int = & p_int; |  0 |   &x  |  &p_int | <-- begin: all variables lead to x
-------------------------+----+-------+---------|
*p_int = 12;             | 12 |   &x  |  &p_int |
**p_p_int = 25;          | 25 |   &x  |  &p_int |
-------------------------+----+-------+---------| <-- end: all variables lead to x
p_int = 12;              | 25 |   12  |  &p_int | <-- p_int now points to garbage
*p_p_int = 3;            | 25 |    3  |  &p_int |
-------------------------+----+-------+---------|
p_p_int = 27;            | 25 |    3  |    27   | <-- p_p_int now points to garbage
------------------------------------------------/
```

I've used `undef` to indicate that the variable does not yet exist (i.e. is undefined); `&x` and `&p_int` to represent the addresses of those variables (since an exact value is not knowable).

This is a thought exercise to see if you understand different levels of indirection, if you realize that `*p_int` and `p_int` refer to different values in memory. As you noticed, it does not compile. Assigning a numeric literal to a pointer is almost certainly an error, of no use outside this sort of thought experiment. In real code, a line like `p_int = 12` is probably a typo (likely intended to be `*p_int = 12`) and the compiler will alert you to this.

Fortunately, the author seems to be aware of the inadvisability of trying to access the memory at addresses `12`, `3`, and `27`, as neither `p_int` nor `p_p_int` was de-referenced while storing a bogus address. Still, it would be nice if the author acknowledged these limitations, or better yet devised an exercise that does not need such a disclaimer. (Hopefully this was an isolated slip. *Unlike some people, I would not denounce an entire book on the basis of a single exercise. Books are long, C++ is complex, and [mistakes happen](https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html).* )

Comment: No, you're wrong. You cannot assign an `int` to a pointer without an explicit cast in C++. Moreover, evaluating a pointer like `p_int = (int*)12` causes undefined behavior so that is no longer valid C++.

Comment: @Ayxan Did you read the part where I wrote "if the code were to actually compile"? The part where I wrote "This is a thought exercise"?? The part where I wrote "it does not compile"??? The part where I wrote "the compiler will alert you to this"???? The part where I wrote "neither `p_int` nor `p_p_int` was de-referenced while storing a bogus address"?????

Comment: once you cause undefined behavior, you can no longer reason about the program in any meaningful way. Since your explanation assumes UB, you are not talking about C++ anymore. Even if this is a theoretical experiment. Pointers aren't just int`s. You can't just convert any old int to a pointer and expect well-defined behavior.

Comment: *For future reference:* I have reviewed the comments by Ayxan and determined that they are incorrect. The behavior is implementation-defined, not undefined. It is valid C++, and one can reason about it in a meaningful way.

Comment: I am not sure how you reviewed anything but the question I posted didn't get any satisfying answer, thus I didn't accept any of the answers. Even if it was just implementation defined, your "thought exercise" assuming no implementation whatsoever makes no sense in any meaningful way as I noted before (how can you assume implementation defined behavior for no implementation?).

Comment: @Ayxan I believe a more accurate assessment is that the question you posted did not get an answer saying that the result is UB, thus you did not accept any of the answers. You are wrong, but refuse to accept it. I am not changing my answer to match your major misconceptions.